# Detect when all CSS rules have been applied and painted

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser, paint

During the process of rendering a web page, there is a delay between the time at which a stylesheet is loaded and the time at which all the rules in that stylesheet are applied and the painting is completed.

This delay is dependent on the size of the stylesheet, and the complexity of the rules.

Is there a reliable way to check when the painting process has been completed?

**Note:** I'm looking for a way that will also work when CSS rules are applied dynamically, i.e. when new stylesheets are added to the page or when styles are modified by JavaScript. So `document.onload` is not an option here.

**Context:** I'm working on a large-scale single-page app, which loads stylesheets on the fly. To avoid a [flash of unstyled content](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content#:%7E:text=A%20flash%20of%20unstyled%20content,before%20all%20information%20is%20retrieved.), I'm showing a spinner, and I need to know exactly when to hide it.

Comment: There is no such event available.

Comment: @Cerbrus I'm aware of that. But maybe there's a workaround? Using `getComputedStyles()` or `requestAnimationFrame()` perhaps?

Comment: What if you listen for "loaded" events on the stylesheets, then in the handler, call `setTimeout` (without delay) to give the browser a moment to render the freshly loaded stylesheet, before you hide the spinner?

Comment: I've tried that, and it's being executed before all the rules are applied

Comment: Eh, how large are your stylesheets? Rendering is what browsers are best at, what are you doing that makes the rendering take _that_ long? What if you add a small delay? say, 100ms?

Comment: It doesn't take too long, less than a second, but you can see the styles being applied for a brief moment, so i'm trying to avoid that. A small delay helps, but i'm wondering if there's a better way.

Comment: I'd say the most reliable solution would be to add a small delay after the css loaded event...

Comment: I suppose you're right, since the rendering process should take longer than that anyway. I would consider that a valid answer.

Comment: What counts as rendering? What about FOUC/FOUT? What about animations that start on page load?

Comment: @BoltClock FOUC is exactly what i'm trying to avoid. The only animation that starts on page load is the spinner in my case.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'd say the most reliable solution would be to add a small delay after the css loaded event.

Something like this pseudo-code:

```
myCssTag.onload(function(){
    setTimeout(doStuffAfterRender, 100);
});
```

Comment: What is desired is 100% reliable, not "most reliable".

Comment: @SzczepanHołyszewski: So you downvote the most reliable method that _exists_? This is the only real option available.